# A question concerning the paper "Safarevic's theorem on solvable groups as Galois groups"

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Theorem 15 in the paper [Safarevic's theorem on solvable groups as Galois groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809211) by Schmidt and Wingberg.

The proof has four steps.

In the fourth step, $x$ is a class in $H^1(k_S|K,\mathcal E(n, ν))$, where
$x_\mathfrak p$ is cyclic for all $\mathfrak p \notin T$.

But is $\varphi_{n,v+1}|_{G_{(N_v^n)_\mathfrak p}} + x_\mathfrak p$ cyclic for all $\mathfrak p \notin T$?

Comment: The proof is also contained in the book "Cohomology of number fields" by Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg. Maybe this is explained there.

Comment: It's the same as the proof in the paper. Actually, the problem came up when I was reading the book.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the authors?

Comment: I don't know the contact information of the authors

Comment: schmidt@mathi.uni-heidelberg.de